# parse Location services

Tags: parse-platform, geolocation, parse-server, parse-android-sdk

Hello i want to do a Location section within my app . And what i want to accomplish i havent seen it in documentations. I want to walk from point A to point B and when i cover distance i want for the app to track the trace like uber does with the cars. I can take which ever track i want to in order to get to point B. i want it to register with a line as i walk and at the end be able to see what route i took to get to point B.Is there any documentation over this i simply dont find it. how can i accomplish this ?.

Comment: I'd try to store the sequence of geopoints in an Array and then use these points to plot the trace in the map. Can you please try to do this and report in the case you have any problem?

Comment: To simplify the process of storing the points you can encode and decode a string. Example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geometry-encodings